# Symfony2 : 404 Not Found without app.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, apache2

This is my htaccess in public_html directory :

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And this is /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain_com.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
        ServerName  mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DocumentRoot /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.com/public_html
        # DirectoryIndex app.php
        <Directory /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.com/public_html>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
        </Directory>

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>


        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And these are results :

- **mydomain.com** => Redirects to **mydomain.com/app.php/** and then works fine.
- **mydomain.com/post/** => 404 Not Found
- **mydomain.com/app.php/post/** => works fine.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the mod_rewrite of apache enabled? If not, enable it, restart the server and try again.

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this virtual host with your setting

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/yourdomain.com/web/"
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
    <Directory "/path/to/yourdomain.com/web/">
        DirectoryIndex app.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/app\.php/(.*) /$1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```